# Opening script saved on a cluster with local spyder installation

Tags: python, ssh, anaconda, spyder

I have anaconda, hence spyder, installed on a local machine. What I am trying to do is to use my local spyder installation to open a .py script saved on a remote cluster (in my office) via ssh. The issues that I am encountering are the following:

1. I cannot run spyder from the cluster - there is no graphical device whatsoever. For example, we have actually anaconda installed on the cluster, but when I ran `spyder` from the command line, I get the following error message: `Could not connect to any X display`
2. I cannot mount the (remote) drivers, where the .py scripts are located, onto my local machine when I am working from home (which is the case when I am at work, connected to the internet via cable). If this was the case, I could simply launch spyder on my local machine, then open the scripts. I can only access the files on some drivers mounted onto the cluster via ssh.

As, however, I can access the .py scripts saved on the cluster via ssh (I can open then with programs installed locally e.g. vim, jpico etc), I was wondering whether it is possible to use the command line to open a script saved on a remote cluster using my local spyder installation, something like `$ spyder /path/to/myScript/savedOnTheRemoteCluster.py`

Comment: You can do X-forwarding of the Spyder running on the cluster (that's what I have done on a daily basis when working with university resources from afar). Use something like X2Go, Nomachine....

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) As of May 2019 our editor is not capable of working with files on remote locations. So your best option right now is to mount your remote server with [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) to make it appear as a local directory and then open any file present there in Spyder.